# Does JetBrains Fleet have any way to import settings (a la PyCharm / IntelliJ / etc)?

Tags: jetbrains-fleet

A crucial part of the `JetBrains` family of editors is the ability to customise their wonderful editor. I had thought that `Fleet` would then provide exactly that.  I don't see any "Import/Export Settings" and the `keymap` is apparently limited presently to just three hard-coded options?

[image]

Are there any hidden ways to "get at" the keyboard shortcuts - that's essential for the viability of this too that I am really looking forward to using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Import keymap from IntelliJ or another IDE:** not possible right now and still  not planned for any specific future version.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/FL-10312 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified with any progress.

A request to bundle more keymaps: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/FL-15355

Also ...

> ... the number of default shortcuts is *deliberately low*, and only the most important actions have a default key binding. This allows for more freedom in assigning a custom shortcut when you need one.

---

**Customizing keymap/shortcuts:** please check the official help pages: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/keymap.html

> *Review and edit key bindings*
>
> Press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + K</kbd> and start typing `Edit Keymap`. Select the `Edit Keymap action`.
>
> [image]
>
> The list of key bindings appears.
>
> [image]

---

**Export to/import from another Fleet installation/computer:** I believe right now it will be just direct copying of config files (  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/keymap.html#93f97231 ):

- `keymap.json` for keymap (you can access it using the `Edit Keymap JSON File` action)
- `user.json` (the `keymap` array there) -- you customizations made via IDE.

IDE-wide settings files location: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/fleet/settings.html#user-settings-file-locations

> Fleet settings are stored under `.fleet` in the user directory:
>
> | OS | Path |
> | --- | --- |
> | Windows | `C:\Users\user_directory\.fleet\settings.json` |
> | Linux | `/home/user_directory/.fleet/settings.json` |
> | macOS | `/Users/user_directory/.fleet/settings.json` |

Comment: thx for the heads up .  The "legacy expectations/behavior " in the existing IDE's  are precisely what I look for so I'm unlikely to use this product